# How is equation of a circle in Argand plane given by $z\bar z + a \bar z + \bar a z+ b = 0$?

Tags: complex-numbers, circles

My book gives the equation  $z\bar z + a \bar z + \bar a z+ b = 0$  for general equation of circle with centre -a and radius $\sqrt {a \bar a - b}$. I can understand that general equation of a circle can be $|z-z_0|=r$ or $z \bar z - z_0 \bar z -\bar z_0 z + z_0 \bar z_0 - r^2 = 0$, but how does that give rise to this equation? I am referring to the formula list in the Arihant 39 years JEE solved papers.

Comment: Compare coefficients of $z$ and $\bar z$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that\begin{align}z\overline z+a\overline z+\overline az+b=0&\iff(z+a)\overline{(z+a)}=a\overline a-b\\&\iff|z+a|^2=a\overline a-b.\\&\iff\bigl|z-(-a)\bigr|^2=a\overline a-b.\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

In

$$
Z \bar Z = r^2
$$

making $Z = z + a$

$$
(z+a)(\bar z + \bar a) = r^2
$$

or

$$
z\bar z+z \bar a+ \bar z a + a\bar a -r^2 = 0
$$